# how to use substring and cast as time in u-sql

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

how can we substring a column and cast it as time in u-sql

```
@mergeddata =
SELECT DISTINCT a.hta_coinsid.Substring(12, 5).time 
AS CreatedTime                    FROM @file1 AS AS;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results really help with this type of question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you viewed the documentation? Specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/csharp-functions-and-operators#substring